# Chat client for various chat services

Tags: java, chat

I'd recently worked on a project **`chat-server`**.
For that I'd two things: one is my *server* and the other is *client*.
In this, the *client* had to only know the ***IP*** of the server and the ***port no.***
Now I want to make a chat *client* for **gtalk, facebook** etc. for that I need to be *authentic*(get `username` and `password` verified by those servers), ***IP*** and the ***port no.*** of the *server*.
Can anybody help me out in that how to get verified the `username` and `password` of the `user`? The ***IP*** and ***port no.*** of different servers(*gtalk*, *facebook*, etc.).
And what type of data will I receive from the server(number of users online, etc.), and how to parse them in my application? And further how to send the message from the `user` to the server and vice-versa?

Comment: Do check this out [Oracle Site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/jellema-googletalk-094343.html). It includes the step by step explaination with coding, for making the Google Chat client. Hope that will help more. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to know, what configuration is used by what service provider, you need to walk through their API's, if they are open for Developers to see. For instance related to gtalk : 
Hope this link will give you knowledge regarding everything you need to make. [Google Talk Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/talk_developers_home.html).